# get absolute path of file without filename using Python pathlib

Tags: python-3.x, directory, path, pathlib

I want to replace `file_location = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`
with `pathlib` to get the aboslute path of the file without the filename

with using  `directorypath = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve()`
gives me the absolute path + the filename

how can I get the absolute path without the filename ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use '.parent':  `directorypath = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent`
[Path.parent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent)